# "an immer" in the sentence

Tags: grammar

There is the following sentence:

> Simon betont, dass der große Fehler der sowjetischen Propaganda war,
>   "dass sie sich von Anfang an immer mit dem Westen verglichen hat".

Question is, why before "immer" there is "an"?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

These are two separate expressions, **von Anfang an** and **immer (...) verglichen hat**.

Think:

> ...dass sie sich immer mit dem Westen verglichen hat. Damit hat sie
>   gleich von Anfang an begonnen.

Answer (score 14):

I'm only a student of German, but I'm going to hazard the opinion that the "an" does not precede "immer", it follows "Anfang".

Comment: How long have you been learning German, Marty? Your feel for the language is quite impressive already.

Comment: A dank, Kage. Ich well Euch entfern auf mein dialekt. Mit finf un dreisig jahr zurick hob ich studiert zwei jahr Deutsch in der Uni. Nach etliche zehndlig jahren, is mir 'erein-gefallen in die haent 'erein a Paar alte Jiddische bicher, was ich hob ongehojben zu lesen mit der Hilf vun mein klein kenntenis Deutsch. Ich bin ingichen verwandelt in a verbrennter Jiddischist, gegangen in a jaerliche Lager (retreat) in New York, verfasst Lieder, un ibergesetzt a memoir vun Jiddisch leben in alt-Rusland.

Comment: Jetzt hast du mich überrascht! Ich verstehe alles, was du geschrieben hast, aber selbst könnte ich nicht so schreiben. Die Aussprache klingt ein Bisschen wie bayerischer Dialekt, aber doch ganz anders :-). Respekt jedefalls @_@=b.

Answer (score 1):

As Marty notes, the "an" belongs to "von Anfang an", not to the "immer".

> Simon betont, dass der große Fehler der sowjetischen Propaganda war, "dass sie sich von Anfang an immer mit dem Westen verglichen hat".

But the sentence is a mess and wrong. What was compared with "the West"? The soviet Propaganda? That's nonsense. But 'sie sich' says exactly that.

> Simon betont, dass der Fehler der sowjetischen Propaganda war, "dass die Sowjetunion sich von Anfang an immer mit dem Westen verglichen hat".

From a logical viewpoint: Wenn sie sich immer mit dem Westen verglichen hat, dann folgt daraus, dass sie sich von Anfang an verglichen hat.

Aber gut - Sprache ist nicht strikt auf Sparsamkeit bedacht; man möchte vielleicht den Aspekt, dass der Vergleich gerade zu Beginn nicht förderlich war, betonen. Dann sind es aber m.M. nach 2 Halbsätze, die besser getrennt gehören, als verbunden, denn "von Beginn an immer" ist schlecht.

> Simon betont, dass der Fehler der sowjetischen Propaganda war, "dass die Sowjetunion sich von Anfang an und immerfort mit dem Westen verglichen hat".

Since the second part of the sentence is marked as citation, it might be preferable to make a remark:

> Simon betont, dass der Fehler der sowjetischen Propaganda war, "dass sie (sic! gemeint ist wohl die Sowjetunion, Anm. XY) sich von Anfang an immer mit dem Westen verglichen hat".

Comment: This sentence comes from this page http://www.dw-world.de/dw/article/0,,15335117,00.html . I guess that the West means western countries in Europe like Germany or France.

Comment: Yes, but 'sie' in this sentence is the propaganda, but what is meant, is the Soviet Union. "The Soviet propaganda compared itself with the West" - no! It compared the Soviet Union with the West, not itself.

Comment: Du hast zwar recht, dass die Formulierung schlecht ist, aber Du kannst nicht einfach ein Zitat verändern ohne das kenntlich zu machen.

Comment: @CarstenSchultz: Du hast vollkommen recht.